# SSRS cangrow = false not working when report is deployed to reporting server

Tags: reporting-services

I've been hunting around online for any clues into this, and don't seem to see anyone with the same problem. I have a fairly straightforward table or matrix in a report, and I set cangrow to false for all the textboxes inside. This behaves as expected while testing it inside Visual Studio. However, when I deploy it to the report server and run it in I.E., the cangrow field appears to just get ignored and some of the textboxes get HUGE, which is undesirable.

I work on a small team in a large company, and we have no direct control over the report server itself, and thus I also don't know much about that side of things, but I am guessing there's some kind of configuration issue with the server that is causing it to ignore the cangrow setting? If I can get more specifics I can maybe convince the server management team to make the change but as it stands I have nothing helpful for them and this is a seriously isolated issue.

I've tested this with multiple different reports, tables and matrixs, all manner of settings on my end, but nothing seems to have any effect. From what I've seen, CanGrow has been in SSRS for some time so I don't imagine it's a version issue? I'm even deployed to two different reporting servers (versions 10.50 and 11.21) and both had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with CanGrow = False being ignored when using the web-based viewer (RPL) after deployment in SSRS.

The only workaround that actually worked (at least in Sql Server Reporting Services 2008 R2) is to set the Row Vertical Alignment to **Top**, as shown in the following image:

[image: Workaround for CanGrow=False in RPL Viewer]

In this way the cell with long contents correctly cuts its contents.

I had no need to change the padding or do other changes (as some Google results suggest, which maybe is of help only when the cell has no contents).

Answer (score 1):

Use **Rectangle** to hold that particular field in a constant size.

Cut the textbox of the particular field and insert a rectangle in that place and then paste back the textbox. This rectangle would keep the size constant for the field.(do this for both header and details row if needed)

If you need all the fields to be in constant size, then place the entire table in the rectangle.